# How to convert NSString of Decimal to NSString of Bytes

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have a very big integer value in decimal which i put in NSString , i need to convert to NSString of Bytes value for this big value how can i do it? FYI the length of NSSting is "308"

Please help

Thanks

Comment: I need in binary format (byte array values).

Comment: HI Mike 
by the below code i am getting the same decimal string data when i print as NSstring again ,but i should get the actual binary data which is unreadable chars?

Comment: Do you mean a string of 308 char of ASCII digits [0-9], and you want to convert it into binary format? That is around 100 bytes long, or something like a 800-bit integer, if my estimate is correct. You could write a function that reads one digit, converts it into binary, and then multiplies it by 10. But you'll have to handle overflow yourself. Unless there's a bignum library for doing this.

Answer (score 3):

To do this, you'll need to do the following(assuming you want a UTF8-encoded byte stream):

```
NSString *myString; //Assuming your string is here
NSData *stringData = [myString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]; //This is the NSData representation of the string
const void *bytes = [stringData bytes]; //This are the raw bit array values
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean "string of bytes"?

In particular, an NSString can only encapsulate strings with valid unicode (and some more primitive non-unicode) encodings.  Thus, "string of bytes" may not actually make sense.

If you really want raw bytes, you can convert it to an NSData instance using the `dataUsingEncoding:*` methods (there are two, depending on need).